# Why did Nozik use differential (not different) in 'differential entitlements' and 'differential deserts'?

Tags: discussion

Can [Why did Nozick use differential (not different) in 'differential entitlements' and 'differential deserts'?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/63799/8572) be salved? I've rewritten it to focus on Nozick's diction.

Answer (score 1):

I imagine the reason Nozick used "differential" in the following phrase

> past circumstances or actions of people can create differential entitlements or differential deserts to things

rather than "different" is due to his rhetorical style. I would have used the word "different" but I prefer shorter words.

However, the concern is whether the question can be saved.

When I read the question I asked myself, *What difference would it make if Nozick used the other word?* I couldn't see any real difference. Then I wondered why the question was being asked. Perhaps addressing that may save the question: *In what way does it matter, from a philosophical perspective, which word he used?*